# php 5.3 and APC (what's going on)?

Tags: php, c, apc

I am trying to get a version of APC that works with PHP 5.3.x

According to several online resources including [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_PHP_Cache#Alternative_PHP_Cache), the version of APC given as compatible with PHP 5.3.x is APC-3.1.3p1

However upon investigating the contents of the file, in the file named INSTALL

The first few lines declare:

> ### Installation Instructions for APC
>
> This version of APC should work on PHP
>   4.3.0 - 4.4.x and
>   5.1.0 - 5.2.x.  Yes, that means PHP 5.0.x is no longer  supported.  Upgrade to PHP 5.1.x or 5.2.x and you
>   will  notice all sorts of performance
>   increases.

**No mention is made of 5.3**

So which version of APC is to be used for building a dso for PHP 5.3.x ?

Comment: [Yet another instance of PHP documentation being wrong.](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=23877)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[APC's changelog](http://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=APC&release=3.1.3p1) explicitely mentions PHP 5.3, so it's just an outdated INSTALL file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `pecl` program unavailable to you?  `pecl install apc` *should* work, and will automatically grab the extension version most appropriate for your PHP version.

If you don't have `pecl`, and you got your PHP installation from your operating system, check their repositories for the `php-pecl` package.  Under some distributions, `pecl` is provided by the `php-pear` package instead.  (Even then, there may well be a `php-pecl-apc` package...)

Comment: 'pecl install apc' does not work. It fails to build. there is a duplicate static in one of the files (can't remember which)

Comment: It's very likely you're going to encounter that same error if you attempt a manual install.  It will be helpful for you to try a manual install of the latest version and see if that's the case.  If so, editing your original post with the full and complete error will be helpful if Google turns up nothing.